# Convert Specific Revit View to IFC Using Forge Model Derivatives

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

Is there a way to translate only a specific view to IFC using the Forge Model Derivatives API? More specifically, is there a way to make it so "only export elements visible in view" were checked in the Revit export settings with a particular view selected?

Answer (score 0):

To enable `Export only elements visible in view`, you need to the following:

1. Create a new [IFC Export Setup Option](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/revit-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2020/ENU/Revit-DocumentPresent/files/GUID-E029E3AD-1639-4446-A935-C9796BC34C95-htm.html), and check `Export only elements visible in view`, then give it a name to save it in the RVT file
2. Save changes to the RVT file
3. Update the modified RVT model with your own IFC export option to your Forge bucket
4. Submit a translation via [POST job](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) and specify your IFC export option name in the `advanced.IFCExportOption` like below:

```
{
   "input": {
     "urn": "{YOUR_RVT_BASE64_URN}"
   },
   "output": {
     "formats": [
       {
         "type": "IFC",
         "views": [
           "3d"
         ],
         "advanced": {
            "IFCExportOption": "{YOUR_IFC_EXPORT_OPTION_NAME}"
         }
       }
     ]
   }
 }
```